# Object Assign Alternative

Tags: jquery

I have very little understanding of Javascript/jQuery so not sure how easy this is to fix... I have the below script to toggle 4 hidden divs at the bottom of separate pages and it works fine apart from in Internet Explorer (IE 11).

The debugger says "jQuery.Deferred exception: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign' TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign'" and my script has Object.assign in it. I'm just wondering if anybody knows of an alternative solution?

The code I have is as follows:

```
(function($) {

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var panel1 = new Panel(1),
        panel2 = new Panel(2);          panel3 = new Panel(3);          panel4 = new Panel(4);

    $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller1', function() {
         panel1.togglePanel();
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller2', function() {
         panel2.togglePanel();
    });         $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller3', function() {
         panel3.togglePanel();
    });         $(document).on('click', '.tab-controller4', function() {
         panel4.togglePanel();
    });
});

// Constructor. Needs to get the number 1 or 2
function Panel(num) {
    var that = this; // Remember the object that is created here
    Object.assign(that, {
        isVisible : false,
        showMessage : null,
        hideMessage : null,
        animationDuration : 300,
        animationEasing : 'linear',

        init: function() {
            that.hidePanel();
        },

        hidePanel : function() {
            // Use number to address the correct class, here and below.
            $('.infoToggle' + num).animate({
                bottom : -(that.getAnimationOffset())
            }, that.animationDuration, that.animationEasing, function() {
                that.isVisible = false;
                that.updateTabMessage();
            });
        },

        showPanel : function() {
            $('.infoToggle' + num).animate({
                bottom : 0
            }, that.animationDuration, that.animationEasing, function() {
                that.isVisible = true;
                that.updateTabMessage();
            });
        },

        togglePanel : function() {
            (that.isVisible ? that.hidePanel : that.showPanel)();
        },

        updateTabMessage : function() {
            if (that.isVisible) {
                $('.tab-controller' + num + ' .close').show();
                $('.tab-controller' + num + ' .show').hide();
            } else {
                $('.tab-controller' + num + ' .close').hide();
                $('.tab-controller' + num + ' .show').show();
            }
        },

        getAnimationOffset : function() {
            return $('.panel-content' + num).height();
        }
    });
    // call init here, which will execute when you do `new Panel`:
    that.init();
} })(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could just use the polyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution if you use compilation for your project. You might consider to add at the top of your entry point

```
import 'core-js'
```

At the moment [core-js polyfill library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-js) is the easiest way to make Cross Browser Support